# How to save a web page as PDF in Computer (I need convert the webpage into PDF with exactly What I see)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, mac, chrome-web-store

I am viewing a docker tutorial. I am running the docker image of https://github.com/dockersamples/101-tutorial in my local.

Now when I try to print the webpage using chrome browser then in the print preview I see a dinosaur which is not present in the webpage but only in the print preview.

How can I save the webpage as a PDF in this case using any browser or addon, etc?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. It might be on topic in [su] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 0):

In case of MAC, I see that you can use Safari browser to print the webpage. I tested with Safari version 13.1

I see that Safari browser prints/saves the webpage as PDF correctly without any dinosaur image